# How do I use a Firebase Function to get a stripe emphemeral key in iOS?

Tags: javascript, ios, firebase, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

I'm trying to get an emphemoral key from stripe using firebase functions. Here is the error I see in my firebase logs:

> getStripeEphemeralKeysUnhandled error TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined at exports.getStripeEphemeralKeys.functions.https.onCall (/workspace/index.js:40:42) at func (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:273:32) at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)

Here is the error that shows in the xcode console:

> Error creating ephenmeral key: Error Domain=com.firebase.functions Code=13 "INTERNAL" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=INTERNAL} INTERNAL

firebase function written in Javascript:

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const stripe_key = "sk_test_LT2Wc4v9kUD6XxG8Nq2LNh4P00thTqtiSa"  
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
var stripe = require('stripe')(stripe_key);
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.createStripeCustomer = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  const full_name = data.full_name;
  const email = data.email;
  const customer = await stripe.customers.create({
      email: email,
      name: full_name,
      description: full_name
  });
  console.log('new customer created: ', customer.id)
  return {
      customer_id: customer.id
  }
});

exports.getStripeEphemeralKeys = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  const api_version = data.api_version;
  const customer_id = data.customer_id;
  const key = await stripe.ephemeralKeys.create (
      {customer: customer_id},
      {apiVersion: api_version}
  );
  return key;
});
```

iOS call using swift

```
func createCustomerKey(withAPIVersion apiVersion: String, completion: @escaping STPJSONResponseCompletionBlock) {
        let stripe_customer_id = MyDefaults.getDefaultsForCustID()
        functions.httpsCallable("getStripeEphemeralKeys").call(["api_version" : apiVersion, "customer_id" : stripe_customer_id]) { (response, error) in
            if let error = error {
                completion(nil, error)
            }
            if let response = (response?.data as? [String: Any]) {
                completion(response, nil) 
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm not versed enough in Javascript to know what the error means except there seems to be a problem with the word create. Any thoughts are much appreciated!

Comment: The error message is telling you that `stripe.ephemeralKeys` is undefined.  What do you expect it to be instead?  Where does `stripe` come from?  Please edit the question to show the entire code sample

Comment: HI @DougStevenson, Thank you -  I am showing the entire code now. I am expecting to use this firebase function to get an ephemeral key from stripe. stripe is a dependency i'm using in the cloud function.

Comment: What version of Stripe are you using here?

Comment: @floatingLomas my package.json says  "stripe": "^8.103.0" but stripe customer service says I am using an outdated version... still trying to figure out how that is happening.

Comment: It's possible that the value of `stripe_key` is wrong and therefore the `stripe` variable is not being properly populated and results in the `undefined` error mentioned by Doug. Try checking if the value is correct, also, the latest version of Stripe is 8.104.0, you can also try upgrading it.

Comment: Thanks, @RafaelLemos. The key is correct because I have another stripe func that works. When I figure out how to upgrade stripe on the firebase server I'll post it here.

Answer (score 1):

OK Thanks @floatingLomas #Rafael Lemos. You guys were on the right track. It was the stripe version. I was having some pod errors that I was pushing to fix later so cleaned up and updated cocoa pods ruby and npm... now when I firebase deploy - I finally got the right version of stripe up to firebase...

I"M GOOD NOW -- THANKS!!!